# How do I take very long exposure photos?

Tags: camera

I would like to take some long exposure photos using my Android phone (Moto DROID v1 running Android 2.2.2) of the night sky.  I experimented with the settings for the default camera app, and I found that I can set the focus to infinity, but the exposure time has only three settings: 0, +1, and +2.  If I  set the exposure to +2, I can get a recognizable photo of a full moon, but I am unable to capture a field of stars.

Is there any way to extend the exposure time beyond +2?

Comment: **Note**: there's a misunderstanding between [exposure compensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposure_compensation?oldformat=true) and [shutter speed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shutter_speed?oldformat=true). The exposure setting on the camera app is the first one, not about the duration of the exposure.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this from with Settings of the default camera.

You could look at another camera app like [Camera Streak](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.zalzala.streak) ([Blog](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/camera-streak-for-android-simulates-long-exposure-photography/)).

Or you could roll your own, here is the relevant details you need to change:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html

[setExposureComponent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setExposureCompensation%28int%29)

Comment: I tried camera streak, but without tight control over ISO I just wound up with either a black image or a bright, fuzzy blob.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Long Exposure Camera 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.longexposure2). This app can be used to achieve very long shutter exposure.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Camera FV-5. It only lets you go up to 1 minute exposure, but it has ISO control, and the Lite version isn't restricted or watermarked.